# DOMCharacterDataModified not firing consistently across Firefox and Chrome. Who is correct?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom-events

I made this fiddle that listens for a few different `MutationEvents`, specifically `DOMCharacterDataModified`, `DOMSubtreeModified`, and `DOMNodeInserted` when changing the `innerHTML` of a div.

http://jsfiddle.net/newtang/kysTm/15/

Interestingly, Chrome shows:
`DOMCharacterDataModified`, `DOMSubtreeModified`

while Firefox 5 shows: `DOMNodeInserted`.

I'm not actually sure who's correct.  I found this old Mozilla bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=368133 and the W3 docs (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html), but I don't find either particularly enlightening.

Does anyone know what the proper behavior is?  I'd love to file a bug on someone so it's consistent.

Comment: I filed this Chromium bug based on the answers: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88195

Comment: Opened a Webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox's behaviour seems to be correct. You setting the innerHTML, so you do not change the characterData of an existing textNode, you insert a new textNode and remove any existing contents .(You may also observe DOMNodeRemoved in your example, you'll see that it fires too)

See the difference when really modifying the data of a textNode: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/yQu8v/

Answer (score 3):

WebKit has an "optimization" where if you set innerHTML to something that contains no markup and the first child of the node you're setting it on is a Text node they will modify the text in the textnode directly instead of doing what the spec calls for (removing all the children and creating a new Text child).  Hence the difference in mutation events.